# dropdown form_helper codeigniter 2.4 line 325

Tags: codeigniter-2, codeigniter-form-helper

some body helpme. i have same error like that

"Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: helpers/form_helper.php

Line Number: 325"

this is my model, controller, and view code

> function get_data()
>       {
>         $query = $this->db->get('
>         if ($query->num_rows() > 
>           {
>            return $query->row_array();
>           }else{
>           return FALSE;
>           }

//controller

> {  $data['title'] = "project";  $data['main_content'] =
>   'jurnal_proyek/display';  $this->jurnal_model->set_project(); 
>   $data['journal_data'] = $this->jurnal_model->get_data(); 
>   $this->load->view('layout/template', $data); }

//view

> 'Semua', 4 => 'Pendapatan',5 => 'Biaya');    echo form_dropdown('jenis', $options, $selected, $data); 
>   ?>

Answer (score 1):

the formatting was quite bad on your post. I could not follow it well..

read the documentation carefully.  you have 4 parameters; the first is the name, second is an associative array of value/option pairs, third is selected item, fourth is a string of text to be inserted in the select box.

instead of :

```
echo form_dropdown('jenis', $options, $selected, $data);
```

try something like:

```
echo form_dropdown('jenis', $journal_data, $selected);
```